# Cannot get / with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 files jsx:

When I access localhost:8080 It's normal. But when I access localhost:8080/home It's show message in browser **Cannot GET /home**

How can I fix ?

**Home.jsx**:

```
import React from 'react';


class Home extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    render(){

        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Home ...</h1>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
export default Home;
```

**index.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import Home from './Home.jsx';
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';



class App extends React.Component {

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <ul>
                     <li>Home</li>
                 </ul>
                 {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }


}

render((
   <Router history = {browserHistory}>
      <Route path = "/" component = {App}>
         <IndexRoute component = {Home} />
         <Route path = "home" component = {Home} />

      </Route>
   </Router>

), document.getElementById('app'));
```

**File webpack.config.js:**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app');

var config = {
    entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080,
    contentBase: "./src/client",

    hot: true
   },
  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx?/,
        include : APP_DIR,
        loader : 'babel-loader',
        query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `devServer` configuration, you need the `historyApiFallback` setting:

```
   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080,
      contentBase: "./src/client",
      historyApiFallback: true,
      hot: true
   },
```

This tells the `devServer` to always return the root html page and let the client do the routing.  In other words, to *fallback* to the root api route.

Comment: Hi David Tryon . I added but when i access localhost:8080/home It show  in same result localhost:8080. It not switch to home page. Can you help me ?

Comment: At the moment you have the `IndexRoute` and the `home` route pointing to the same place.  So, you will probably get the same result. Try to re-configure your `Route`s.

Comment: render((
   <Router history = {browserHistory}>
      <Route path = "/" component = {App}>
       <IndexRoute component = {Home} />
         <Route path = "home" component = {Home} />
      </Route>
   </Router>
  
), document.getElementById('app'));   It's not working :(

Comment: Oh yeah , it working fine with your way. Because a moment ago  I'm not run terminal "npm run build" so not apply project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

change `<Route path = "home" component = {Home} />` to `<Route path = "/home" component = {Home} />`

Comment: It's still not working. Can you have another way ? :(